# Join two ListViews

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a ToDo-App that saves the ToDo's in Firestore.
I am already able to add every new ToDo Item to Firestore and now I want those Items that were added to pop up when the application opens.

I have made the following:

```
body: Column(
    children:<Widget>[
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("TO-DO-Collection").snapshots(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
          return Expanded(
            child: _buildList(snapshot.requireData),
          );
        },
      ),
  Expanded(
  child:ListView(
    children: _getItems(),
  ),
  ),
],
  ),
```

Here the method to build the List with all the stored ToDo's:

```
Widget _buildList(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    final doc=snapshot.docs[index];
    return _buildTodoItem(doc["task"]);
  },
);
```

}
(The function `_buildTodoItem` simply returns a List Tile)

This creates two ListViews (one of the first half of the screen and the other one on the other). Is there any possible way to unify both?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your column with `SingleChildScrollView` and put `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics().` This will merge the scroll of both of your lists.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
child :Column(
  children:<Widget>[
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("TO-DO-Collection").snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(snapshot.requireData);
      },
    ),
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: _getItems(),
    ),
  ],
),),

Widget _buildList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final doc = snapshot.docs[index];
      return _buildTodoItem(doc["task"]);
    },
  );
}
```